# php sessions wont save form data

Tags: php

Here's what I have so far. The problem is when I hit submit it takes me to the next page, but the session does not store the first name. If I remove the action, so it's action="" then the session saves the first name. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

```
...html stuff...

<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ $_SESSION['firstName'] = $_POST['firstName']; }
?>

<form method="POST" action="nextPage.php">
<input name="firstName" type="text" size="70"/>
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to set session in nextPage.php

Comment: Just a guess, in your nextpage did you use `session_start()`? Can you post your nextpage as well?

Comment: $_POST['firstName'] only exists after the form is submitted. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_POST['firstName'] does not exist, until you POST the form data to this page itself. That's why setting the action to "" works, because it posts the form data to itself.

Otherwise, use these two lines of code in the nextPage.php instead of here, and set the session variable in the nextPage instead.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ $_SESSION['firstName'] = $_POST['firstName']; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
...html stuff...
<?php
ob_start(); // add this
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ $_SESSION['firstName'] = $_POST['firstName']; }
?>
```